# SSL Implementation in iOS

Tags: ios, ssl

I am implementing a banking application,I would like to implement SSL,Can anyone help me by telling how to implement SSL in ios,what are the various methods used?

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried searching?

Comment: try:  http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ssl-connections-from-within-iphone-applications/

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.Is there any post which specifies steps/method implementation to be followed while implementing SSL with trusted certificate?